# Big O complexity of two nested loops

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I'm trying to find the Big-O complexity of the following algorithm:

```
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < n; i += 5)
{
    for (j = 1; j < n; j *= 3)
    {
        // O(1) code here
    }
}
```

`n` is the size of an array passed into the method. Struggling with this due to the `i += 5` and `j *= 3`. I know this is probably wrong but I tried the following...

- Outer loop iterates n/5 times. Is that just O(n)?
- Inner loop iterates log3(n) times. Must be just log(n).
- Since they're nested, multiply the complexities together.
- So the Big O complexity is just O(n log(n))?

Comment: Your working is correct. I don't get your question at all.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Originally I was going to just put the code up, but I put my working down to show I'm actually trying to solve the problem and not just getting the answers from you guys. So the complexity is O(n log (n)) ?

Comment: It seems correct to me, although I suggest that you hear other members suggestions and opinions too.

Comment: FYI, this question may have been more appropriate on [cs.se].

Comment: `O(n log n)` is correct

Comment: I'd say having a grip on the time complexity of a rather simple loop should be basic knowledge for any programmer and doesn't get anywhere near the category of "computer science".

Comment: You're right. The complexity is O(n*log(n)). When we talk of the big O notation, we are talking of really large inputs and that's how the functions are defined. So constants do not always matter. So n/5 is simply implying that the function is linear with n and hence the outer loop is O(n).

Comment: @gnasher729 see [On which Stack Exchange should questions about asymptotic runtime complexity analysis be asked?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228634/163250).

Comment: @VivekPradhan Right I see. Thank you for clearing that up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can proceed like the following:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. the time complexity is n(log n)  -- base 3.

Try taking a very large input value for n and you will understand that the graph for [(n/5)*(log3n)]works identical. Hope this helps.